# Apply SequenceReplace with a fixed shift

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sequence

How can I apply `SequenceReplace` with a fixed prespecified shift instead of a shift equal to the length of the pattern, on a given list?

E.g. `SequenceReplace[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}, {a_, b_} /; b - a == 1 :> "z"]` returns `{"z", "z", "z" 6, 9}`, i.e. applies the function on `{1,2}` and `{3,4}`. But I want it to be applied on `{1,2}, {2,3}, {4,5}` and `{z,z,z,z,6,9}` returned. Is there a fast/efficient way to do this?

Comment: "...to be applied on {1,2}, {2,3}..." - but there is no 3 in your list. And what of {5,6}? It fits the rule criteria.

`Flatten[Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}, 2, 
   1] /. {a_, b_} /; b - a == 1 :> "z"]` might be along the lines of what you're after.

Comment: @ciao I fixed it.

Comment: the pairs `{3,4}` and `{5,6}`  also match the pattern in your replacement rule.

Comment: you can also try `BlockMap`:  `BlockMap[Sequence @@ (# /. {a_, b_} /; b - a == 1 :> "z") &, {1, 2, 3,   4, 5, 6, 9}, 2, 1]` or `BlockMap[If[#[[2]] - #[[1]] == 1, "z", Sequence @@ #] &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5, 6, 9}, 2, 1]`.

Comment: Is this function OK? `Split[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}, #2 - #1 <= 1 &]`

Answer (score 5):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

Make one change at a time and wrap it in `FixedPoint`. To see all the intermediate outputs, use `FixedPointList` instead.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f = SequenceReplace[#, {a_, b_} /; b - a == 1 :> Sequence @@ {z, b}, 
    1] &;

(* Thanks to @eldo for the test data *)

alist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9};
blist = {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9};
clist = {1, 4, 8, 1, 2, 11, 23, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9};


FixedPoint[f, #] & /@ {alist, blist, clist} // Column
```

---

[image]

Comment: (+1) Excellent answer, @Syed! Very instructive to continue learning the use of `SequenceReplace`. :-)

Comment: Congrats on your list manipulation gold badge. @E.Chan-López.

Comment: Thanks, @Syed! I owe you a good portion of that list manipulation gold badge. Undoubtedly, the community is a constant source of feedback. :-)

Comment: +1 - Your answer should be very useful for many other  problems too

Comment: Thanks @eldo, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting problem. We cannot use `SequenceReplace` here
because, unlike `SequenceCases`, it doesn't have an `Overlaps` -
option. The only solution I found is rather complicated. Hopefully someone will find a simpler way.

```
ShiftReplace[list_] :=
 Replace[
   ReplaceAll[{a___, {b__, c_}, {d_}} :> {a, {b}, {c}, {d}}] @ 
     Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &], 
   a : {_, __} :> {Table["z", Length[a] - 1]},
   {1}] // Flatten
```

Gap at the end (like question)

```
ShiftReplace[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}]
```

{"z", "z", "z", "z", 6, 9}

Gaps at start and end

```
ShiftReplace[{1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}]
```

{1, 4, "z", "z", "z", "z", 6, 9}

Gaps at start, in between and at the end

```
ShiftReplace[{1, 4, 8, 1, 2, 11, 23, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}]
```

{1, 4, 8, "z", 11, 23, "z", "z", 6, 9}